# contextual id selector css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having trouble with this rule not being applied:

```
h1#header_i { color:red; }
```

This works:

```
h1 { color:red; }
```

This works:

```
#header_i { color:red; }
```

I'm trying to only apply the rule to `<h1>` tags within `id="header_i"` divs.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [the descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors):

```
#header_i h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

http://cssdesk.com/hCxEv

Comment: [Mildly interesting read about contextual selectors in the CSS1 spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors)